# Is there a way to determine target type of an abstract object by including array in Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following class that has to be serialized to JSON and back to the class instance:

```
public class Container {

    private List<Base> derivedOne;
    private List<Base> derivedTwo;

    @JsonCreator
    public Container(@JsonProperty("derivedOne") List<Base> derivedOne, 
                     @JsonProperty("derivedTwo") List<Base> derivedTwo) {
        this.derivedOne = derivedOne;
        this.derivedTwo = derivedTwo;
    }

    public static class Derived1 extends Base {

        private String derivedField1;

        public Derived1(String derivedField1) {
            this.derivedField1 = derivedField1;
        }
    }

    public static class Derived2 extends Base {

        private String derivedField2;

        public Derived2(String derivedField2) {
            this.derivedField2 = derivedField2;
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = 
                  JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Derived1.class, name = "one"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Derived2.class, name = "two")
    })
    public abstract static class Base {
    }

}
```

so that `derivedOne` container is going to hold only Derived1.class instances, and `derivedTwo` - only Derived2.class instances.

Is there a way in Jackson not to use the extra `type` property, to determine the target class by the including container name?

I was trying to get it working with a custom `TypeIdResolver` but without success.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your json value.

You can use **type** to indicate the type of deserialization.

Below is the complete code.

```
public class Container {

    private List<Base> derivedOne;
    private List<Base> derivedTwo;

    @JsonCreator
    public Container(@JsonProperty("derivedOne") List<Base> derivedOne,
                     @JsonProperty("derivedTwo") List<Base> derivedTwo) {
        this.derivedOne = derivedOne;
        this.derivedTwo = derivedTwo;
    }

    public static class Derived1 extends Base {

        private String derivedField1;

        public String getDerivedField1() {
            return derivedField1;
        }

        public void setDerivedField1(String derivedField1) {
            this.derivedField1 = derivedField1;
        }
    }

    public static class Derived2 extends Base {

        private String derivedField2;

        public String getDerivedField2() {
            return derivedField2;
        }

        public void setDerivedField2(String derivedField2) {
            this.derivedField2 = derivedField2;
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include =
            JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Derived1.class, name = "one"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Derived2.class, name = "two")
    })
    public abstract static class Base {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonStr = "{\"derivedOne\":[{\"type\":\"one\",\"derivedField1\":\"derivedField1\"},{\"type\":\"two\",\"derivedField2\":\"derivedField2\"}],\"derivedTwo\":[{\"type\":\"one\",\"derivedField1\":\"derivedField1\"},{\"type\":\"two\",\"derivedField2\":\"derivedField2\"}]}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Container container = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, Container.class);
    }
}
```

use `@JsonTypeIdResolver`.

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include =
            JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonTypeIdResolver(ContainerResolver.class)
    public abstract static class Base {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonStr = "{\"derivedOne\":[{\"type\":\"one\",\"derivedField1\":\"derivedField1\"},{\"type\":\"two\",\"derivedField2\":\"derivedField2\"}],\"derivedTwo\":[{\"type\":\"one\",\"derivedField1\":\"derivedField1\"},{\"type\":\"two\",\"derivedField2\":\"derivedField2\"}]}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Container container = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, Container.class);
    }


public class ContainerResolver extends TypeIdResolverBase {

    private JavaType superType;

    @Override
    public void init(JavaType baseType) {
        this.superType = baseType;
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValue(Object value) {
        return idFromValueAndType(value, value.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object value, Class<?> suggestedType) {

        String typeId = null;
        switch (suggestedType.getSimpleName()) {
            case "Derived1":
                typeId = "one";
                break;
            case "Derived2":
                typeId = "two";
        }
        return typeId;
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String id)  throws IOException {

        Class<?> subType = null;
        switch (id) {
            case "one":
                subType = Container.Derived1.class;
                break;
            case "two":
                subType = Container.Derived2.class;
        }
        return context.constructSpecializedType(superType, subType);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonTypeInfo.Id getMechanism() {
        return JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME;
    }
}
```

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations) article may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently, I use the 'type' property to indicate the target class. But what I wanted to know is whether I could use an external container name to indicate the target class. And the 'type' property would look redundant in this case.

Comment: @androberz ok. I added another way.